# Combine Multiple ISO Files To Burn A Single Bootable ISO Image in windows system

Tags: windows, multi-boot, dvd, iso-image

Suppose I have three iso files "ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso", "ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso, "Window7.iso " I want to combine those multiple ISO files and want to burn a single ISO image file onto DVD that could let me use all of them under windows operating system. How can I do so ?

Comment: If you do this only 1 of 3 will be bootable without major work.  Also the age of the software means you should use either ubuntu ISO.  So many patches have been released since then your better off starting with the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a program such as WinRAR to read/extract ISO's.

If you extract all three ISO's and put contents all in one folder, you can burn this folder to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Since your end goal is  "let me use all of them under windows operating system".  The best choice is to leave them as-is and virtualize.  Get Oracle VirtualBox or VMWare workstation.
Then you can install each ISO into its own virtual machine and you will still be running windows.

The main machine will have to meet the CPU,RAM, and hard drive requirements of all of them together.  While you can do it with less than 4gb of RAM for performance reason I don't recommend it.